# Rails Create 100k rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to optimize creation of 100K rows in rails? I am currently using:

```
hash_numbers = SomeModel.all.map {|number| {number: number}}  
List.last.recipients.create hash_numbers
```

Which gets slower exponentially as the list gets longer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could try one of the batch methods `find_in_batches` or `find_each`, might still be a long process but easier on memory.

Or some method of splitting up the query using `limit` and throwing each group into their own background processes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping your `create` in a transaction so that the db inserts all of your queries in a single transaction?  There might be other better solutions but, since you're using ActiveRecord to do mass insert, give this a try as well:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  1000.times { List.last.recipients.create hash_numbers }
end
```